# jQuery .on not working with dynamic DOM/HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm not *exactly* sure if this is due to my manifest setup, or if there's something going on with the .on event and pages that generate content/modify content on the fly, but I've run into a stumbling block.

Here's the basic idea: I want to be able to catch a click on any link with a URL that matches a pattern regardless of where the user is/what page they're looking at (and do other stuff instead of navigating to the link). The problem I'm running into is that my listener won't work on any page that modifies its content after content loads (jQuery's `$(document).ready`) (e.g. gMail). I'm injecting my javascript all over the place and it's still not quite working.

Here's the listener code (in main.js):

```
$('a[href^="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE"]').on('click', function(event) 
{
  event.preventDefault();
  SKDMmain(this);
});
```

Here's the code in my background.html: (injects my script when the page loads as well as when the tab/window is changed to, so it *should* be there. **Note**: jQuery is included above, along with all of the local .js files I need)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"main.js"});
  });
  chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged.addListener( function(tabID,somethingElse){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID,{file:"main.js"});
  });   

  chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener( function(windowID){
    if ( windowId != chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE ) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"main.js"}); 
    }
  });
</script>
```

But in pages like gMail or [this](http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html#toc-individual), the listener doesn't catch the event. I originally had this as a content script, but I recently moved it to using background and programmatically injecting, but neither seem to be working quite right.

Here's my manifest, for reference:

```
{
"name": "SkedjoolMi",
"version": "0.5",
"description": "Automated Google Calendar event scheduling",
"background_page": "background.html",
"permissions": [
  "tabs","http://*/","https://*/"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery-1-7-1.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
  }
]
}
```

Comment: tabs.onUpdated seems to give a little bit finer resolution (e.g. gMail/Facebook, but it still misses the case in the link I included in that post....

Comment: It also seems as if the listener doesn't work for gmail at all. I've been using the same link to test in various areas http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=aaaa&dates=20110101T060000Z/20110101T060000Z&details=&location=&trp=false&sprop=&sprop=name:

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
$('a[href^="http:.......').on('click', function() { ...
```

Will only work with anchors that are already present when the page is rendered—not dynamically added anchors.  The above is exactly identical to

```
$('a[href^="http:.......').bind('click', function() { ...
```

---

Here's how you use `on` with dynamically added content:

```
$(document).on("click", 'a[href^="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE"]', function() ...
```

This creates a *delegated event*.  All clicks that happen in descendants of your document (which is everything) will be inspected to see if the source of the click matches your selector.  If it does, your event will fire.  That's why it works with dynamically added content.

Ideally, if you can guarantee that all of these anchors will be inside of some container, say, a div with id `foo`, the follow would be more efficient:

```
$('#foo').on("click", 'a[href^="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE"]', function() ...
```

Comment: It still doesn't work if you put the link into the body of an email in gMail, or on Facebook. I have it set to catch `http://` as well as `https://` (although that shouldn't matter - the link is still an `http://`. `main.js` is executing, though, because I can get alerts to pop up. If you inspect the link, it shows as an `<a href>`, but it's buried in `<div>`s, so maybe that's the problem?  As for the div thing, I don't think that's possible - I have no way of knowing where these links will live on the page.

Comment: Note: figured out why it's not working in FB - they wrap their links. I changed the selector, so it now works there. gMail is still a problem, though, likely due to the `iframe` comment from Mark

Comment: i know this is a little old, but just incase someone comes across the issue I was having, $(document).on(... didn't work for me.  I had to change document to $(window).on(... and that worked fine.

Comment: See [here](http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/) to see when use `$(document)` and when use `$(window)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact context here-- it sounds like an inability to jump IFRAME boundaries due to alien domain security.

I would try a timer that tries to gather anything within your target (the gmail doc part of the DOM), if you can do that, you can workaround the inability of jQ live by rolling your own monitor (store the bound links in an array).

Comment: I'm not sure if that's going to work. With a timer, isn't it possible that the user could act between my events firing? I wouldn't exactly want to be injecting JS every second-or-whatever, either. Also, without hand-coding exceptions for every site I find that doesn't work; there's no way in knowing where the content will live. I want this to be functional on all pages :/

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The timer polls for new links dynamically created, binds your method to them, and puts them in an array (so as not to be rebound next tick). As far as knowing where the content will live, maybe that is a point if this method of binding is not the solitary one used for such elems. I have only worked with greasemonkey on this type of thing -- I am not sure of your environment.

Comment: Can you get jQuery to grab targets by using the IFRAME.contentDocument context? (I think it is called contentDocument)

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is working. Here's the code: `var iframe = document.getElementById("canvas_frame");
 var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
 var frameDocBody = iframeDoc.body;
 $(frameDocBody).on("click",'a[href*="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  SKDMmain(this);  
 });`. It _does_ succeed in getting a reference to the body and all that jazz (I was pulling elements out), but it doesn't respond to the click listener :(

Comment: Update: Apparently the issue is that it's not seeing the link in the email as a link. I set it to catch any `a` clicks and it didn't fire, but it did fire for the menu on top (Mail, Calendar, Documents, etc.). Will update with more findings