# get id of li tag which is generating asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get id of  li tags which are added to the page asynchronously after the page load.

I have tried to with function document.ready but it loads before asynchronous li data load.

e.g In my page there is a news data which loads asynchronously & i dont have any control over it. When user clicks on the news link it goes to some location i need to change it to some other location.

I have tried following code. but it is not working.

```
    $("a[href*='Pages/results.aspx']").each(function(){ 
        var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('/Pages/results.aspx', window.location.pathname);
        $(this).attr("href", href);
    });
```

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Comment: I think that this post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867194/jquery-on-not-working-with-dynamic-dom-html

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your li tags via Ajax then I'd recommend throwing your li modification function into the `readystatechange` handler, or the `success` handler if you are using JQuery.

If you are loading the li's via a server back end such as ASP.net then throw your 
I modification function into jQuery's `$(window).load` function.

See: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to create a function the envelopes the creation of the news feed and after that code changes the li?

I think that way it would be in the same thread and would have to execute in the order that you want it to.